# Could a life form evolve a biological video screen as a way of communicating?

Tags: biology, evolution

I was thinking of a situation in which a life form evolves a biological screen somewhere on its body that can play videos.  The life form would play videos on its biological video screen in order to share ideas and memories with other members of its species.  The videos that the life form could play could be simulations of what has happened or could happen in the real world or they could be simulations of entirely fictional worlds.

How would a biological video screen work?  What kind of selective pressure could cause a species to evolve to have a biological video screen?

Answer (score 9):

A good starting point would be the [chromatophores of the 
cuttlefish](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SCrRYDOg_s) which have an amazing range of colors and textures, and can vary at Hz rates. One would assume that [sexual displays](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGvHA5-XnEo) would form the basis for more abstract forms of communications.

Answer (score 8):

Yes,it could happen. But that means the animal would also need very good eyesight to pick up these signals-else they are useless

[image: fish]

Deep sea animals have been doing this for a long time now.

Comment: My day is always better when someone asks a question about some fanciful  creature design, wondering how it might evolve, and the answer comes back "yeah, we already do it."

Comment: @CortAmmon I think my all time favorite answer I ever wrote was for an [anatomically correct land shark](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33083/anatomically-correct-nanaue?answertab=active#tab-top). Goes right with "yeah, we already do it."

Comment: Evolution can bring about better eye sight/better displays as a society desired trait, much as people/animals put up a display of eye catching  parts of their body/abilities for various social exchanges. "Simpsons did it"...

Answer (score 1):

You're basically talking about a smarter octopus. It could definitely happen but they would have to evolve to be more social and less color blind. They would have to find the need to learn how to control their skin to create specific scenes to communicate more than colors to show their mood.

Comment: Cephalopods are not limited in color depth compared to humans, they just see color contrast very differently.  Instead of differentiating by wavelength, they differentiate by polarity; so, while they see a completely different color spectrum than we do, they already perform complex TV like communications this way.  Also, Mimic Octopuses use thier color shows and posturing to resemble a wide range of other sea life ranging from sea snakes to various fish as the need arises... this is already way more complex than just mood coloring.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my oversight

Answer (score 0):

I always figured that cows could be *engineered* to have chromataphore skin inspired by cephalapods, to be used for advertising.

But lab rats used at prototypes could learn to use it as active camouflage and escape: maybe the cephalapod genes also boosted their intelligence more than intended.  After all, it requires processing power to control the display surface.

They would then breed with wild rats which are more genetically varied, and cause all sorts of things to happen with the unplanned interaction between genes.

Comment: Bovine billboard. Just made my day.